# Is the MediaStore.Images.Media._ID unique?

Tags: android, mediastore

when I run through the Android Media Gallery like this:

```
Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
if(mCursor != null){
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Log.d("Picture ID",mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mCursor.close();
}
```

is the returned ID unique, also when a picture was deleted? Or reuse Android the ID, when I delete a picture?

Answer (score 2):

The Media_ID is always unique but there is no guarantee that once the image is deleted it won't be reused again for a new image.