# Android are content IDs unique for items in MediaStore.Images.Media

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213304/is-the-mediastore-images-media-id-unique) so please don't mark this as a duplicate.

My question is: Is `android.provider.BaseColumns._ID` unique regardless of which storage it is placed in?

I ask this because there is no official documentation about it being unique besides it saying `The unique ID for a row.`. The term "unique" could range anywhere from "unique in the directory" to "unique across all files known to the operating system." (If it were truly unique, it should be unique in the universe but we do not expect that.)

The ID might be reused once a file is deleted, the external storage is swapped, etc. but as long as the files remain stable, would the IDs be unique?

Comment: The fact that I wasn't able to find official documentation makes me think I'll find out the hard way if my app crashes due to an ID collision in the database....

Comment: it is unique within the sqlite3 table storing the Image data

Comment: @pskink It would be great if you could provide documentation!

Comment: there is no documentation for that